# Angular error $mdDialog.show is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I am trying to open a modal on click of a button with Angular. On the function called on btn click I am having the code mentioned below:

```
        function openAddVideoModal() {
        var modalInstance = $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: 'createDesign.html',
                controller: 'createDesignCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    currentUser: function () {
                        return _this.currentUser;
                    },
                    postOptions: function() {
                        return {"receiverId":0};
                    }
                },
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose:true,
                fullscreen: false
            });
    }
```

Though, when i click on the button, i receive this error message:

> TypeError: $mdDialog.show is not a function

Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you injected `$mdDialog` in your controller function?

Comment: Yes, I have included it. My controller has the parameters seen below:  

  .controller('Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$mdDialog', '$window', 'CONFIG_CONSTANTS', 'LanguageService', function($rootScope, $scope, $window, $state, $mdDialog, CONFIG_CONSTANTS, LanguageService) {

Comment: Do you have  angular.module('demoApp', ['ngMaterial'])  /// Because $mdDialog seems to be undefined

Answer (score 4):

You had injected dependency in your controller factory function in wrong order

**Change**

```
.controller('Ctrl', [
   '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$mdDialog', '$window', 'CONFIG_CONSTANTS', 'LanguageService', 
     function($rootScope, $scope, $window, $state, $mdDialog, CONFIG_CONSTANTS, LanguageService) {
```

To(moved `$window` from 3rd place to 5th place)

```
.controller('Ctrl', [
  '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$mdDialog', '$window', 'CONFIG_CONSTANTS', 'LanguageService', 
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $mdDialog, $window, CONFIG_CONSTANTS, LanguageService) {
```

Always make sure the dependency have to be used in the similar sequence, the way you have injected them in `inline array` of dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Your inject annotations are not ordered correctly:

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$mdDialog', 
'$window', 'CONFIG_CONSTANTS', 'LanguageService', function($rootScope, 
$scope, $state, $mdDialog, $window, CONFIG_CONSTANTS, LanguageService);
```